# rewriting model order scope in Rails4 , what's the correct syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to upgrade my project to Rails 4 , has_many .. :order => has changed , so I easily rewrote simple statements like :

```
has_many :trackbacks, :dependent => :destroy, :order => "created_at ASC"
```

to

```
has_many :trackbacks, -> { order 'created_at desc' }, :dependent => :destroy
```

however , I am stuck trying to rewrite :

```
 has_many :comments,   :dependent => :destroy, :order => "created_at ASC" do
   # Get only ham or presumed_ham comments
  def ham
     where(:state => ["presumed_ham", "ham"])
  end
  # Get only spam or presumed_spam comments
  def spam
     where(:state => ["presumed_spam", "spam"])
  end
end
```

I tried :

```
 has_many :comments -> { order 'position desc' do
 # Get only ham or presumed_ham comments
 def ham
  where(:state => ["presumed_ham", "ham"])
 end
 # Get only spam or presumed_spam comments
 def spam
  where(:state => ["presumed_spam", "spam"])
 end
end
},   :dependent => :destroy
```

but it doesn't work .. got a syntax error ...  what could be the correct syntax

```
    app/models/article.rb:53: syntax error, unexpected ->, expecting keyword_end
   app/models/article.rb:63: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
     app/models/article.rb:96: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:97: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_end
     app/models/article.rb:97: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
     app/models/article.rb:98: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:99: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:103: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:107: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:109: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:110: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:111: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:291: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:295: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
     app/models/article.rb:531: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
     app/controllers/application_controller.rb:42:in `get_latest_published_articles'
     config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```
has_many :comments,   :dependent => :destroy, -> {where(:state => ["presumed_ham", "ham"]).order("created_at ASC")}
```